# Is there a way to control the gender of your child?

Tags: rune-factory-2

In Rune Factory 2 i have been reading in GameFAQ FAQs/Guides that there are 2 generations in it and that in the second generation you play as your child. looking over the guides there seems to be a list of Bachelorettes and Bachelors implying your child can be a boy or girl.

in [This Guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/938497-rune-factory-2-a-fantasy-harvest-moon/faqs/58394) it says

> Q: Why can I marry the twins as Aria?
>
> A: The two girls don't seem to care for gender, so ..
>       You can do requests for either gendered kid, until the lovelevel reaches
>       a higher number. Then it can only be done by Aaron (Ars) or Aria.

and [this guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/938497-rune-factory-2-a-fantasy-harvest-moon/faqs/59453) says when describer them

> Sera & Serena are Ray's twin daughters. Even though what they like can be
>   different, they have a very good relationship and are always together. They
>   share everything - and that includes you.

the prospect of being able to be a girl in the game and marrying another girl greatly appeals to me and thus i now have my personal marriage goal in the game. the problem is that i can't seem to find any information on exactly how the child of the first generation is decided.

So i am wondering, is there a way to control which gender of child you get or is it random? if random when should i save so i can reload if my child is a boy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia entry for [Rune Factory 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rune_Factory_2:_A_Fantasy_Harvest_Moon#Story) you get to choose whether you have daughter or son, and so which character you play as in the second generation. Essentially the first generation acts as a prologue (or tutorial) for the main story which takes place in the second generation. Since your character in the second generation is the game's main character, the game lets you choose whether you want to play as male or a female.